# has_many :through method on an inherited class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, inheritance, has-many-through, single-table-inheritance

BACKGROUND: I have a simple has_many :through setup linking Communities and Posts - which allows me to call @community.posts or @post.communities. I also have an Events model, which inherits from Posts

OBJECTIVE: I'm wondering if there is a Rails way to call something along the lines of @community.events to return only events belonging to that community.

Comment: what have you tried? I would try declaring the has_many relationship on events as well.

Comment: I tried that, though since events inherit from the post class, shouldn't just declaring them once in post.rb be enough?

Answer (score 0):

Use these associations in the Community model,

```
class Community < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :posts, conditions: {type: nil}
  has_and_belongs_to_many :events, join_table: "communities_posts", association_foreign_key: "post_id"
end
```

For post, you can simply use,

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :communities
```

Comment: unfortunately, i need the relationships to be has_many :through...how would you do it that way?